# Declaring a struct containing an array of pointers to that type of struct

Tags: c, file

I am trying to program a file manager and would like to use folders containing an array of subfolders.

I was thinking of something like

```
struct folder {
 char* name;
 struct folder subfolders [10];
}
```

Is that possbile in any way?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible for a `struct` type to contain an array of the same type  (since the type would generally be diagnosed as incomplete).   Furthermore, if every variable of that type contained one or more members of the same type, the type definition would be infinitely recursive (an A containing an A containing an A .....).

However, a `struct` type can contain a pointer

```
struct folder1
{
    char* name;
    struct folder1 *a_subfolder;
};
```

or an array of pointers

```
struct folder2
{
    char* name;
    struct folder2 *subfolders [10];
};
```

In both cases, code which uses theses types need to take care to ensure the pointers are initialised correctly, and that they are worked with sensibly (e.g. not trying to access the value of an uninitialised pointer, not dereferencing NULL, etc).    Read up on pointers before using this sort of construct - getting things wrong with pointers often means a program that crashes in gruesome ways.

Comment: I agree the diagnostic you will get is "incomplete type", but the *reason* is that such a type would lead to an infinite regress, and if there is anything else in it other than an instance of itself, would also require infinite storage.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this, you need to do this:

```
struct folder {
 char* name;
 struct folder *subfolders [10];
}
```

Now a variable of type `struct folder` contains 10 *pointers* to variables of type `struct folder`.

Before going on, you absolutely need to get familiar with pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Look into linked lists and binary trees first which use a similar concept. There are tons of examples and tutorials on the web (Google "c linked list example").

Your solution:

```
struct folder {
 char* name;
 struct folder subfolders [10];
}
```

doesn't make sense, because each `struct folder` would contain again 10 `struct folder`, each of which would contain 10 `struct folder` and so on until infinity.

But be aware that with your concept each folder can only contain 10 subfolders at most.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct folder {
 char* name;
 struct folder subfolders [10];  // bad
}
```

Is is not possible that way per [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616586/2410359) fine answer as `struct folder` is not fully defined before its complete definition is needed.
`

> Is that possible in any way?

Yes, consider dynamically allocation:

Make functions to create, add a sub-folder, and delete.  Many refinements possible.

```
typedef struct folder_s {
  char* name;
  size_t n;
  struct folder_s **subfolder;
} folder;

folder *folder_alloc(const char *name) {
  folder *root = malloc(sizeof *root);
  if (root) {
    root->n = 0;
    root->subfolder = NULL;
    root->name = strdup(name);
    if (root->name) {
      return root;
    }
    free(root);
  }
  return NULL;
}

folder *folder_add_subfolder(folder *f, folder *sf) {
  size_t new_n = f->n + 1;
  void *tmp = realloc(f->subfolder, sizeof *(f->subfolder) * new_n);
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  f->subfolder = tmp;
  f->subfolder[f->n] = sf;
  f->n = new_n;
  return f;
}

// Only need to free the root folder, recursion will handle the sub-folders.
void folder_free_tree(folder *f) {
  if (f) {
    while (f->n > 0) {
      f->n--;
      folder_free_tree(f->subfolder[f->n]);
    }
    free(f->subfolder);
    f->subfolder = NULL; // Useful for debug
    free(f->name);
    f->name = NULL;  // Useful for debug
    free(f);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is yes, something to that effect would work. You might want to add a `struct folder parentfolder` so you can navigate up as well as down.

Comment: I forcast downvotes for this answers.... Being not able to navigate up is not the problem here.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelWalz. You are confusing a struct and a pointer to a struct.(the latter is allowed)